# PLSQL Update multiple rows with multiple sets

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a long list of data i need to update to a table. Now, i understand how to update, however, i'm struggling to update multiple rows.

Here's my example data:

```
Loc        Check
020201     10000
020301     10050
020401     10100
020501     10150
020601     10200
```

I've attempted different ways based on what i've found on here. But it doesn't quite seem to be what i want.

I was thinking it would be something on the lines of:

```
UPDATE t1
         set check = '10000' where loc = '020201',
         set check = '10050' where loc = '020301',
         set check = '10100' where loc = '020401'
```

Didn't work though :D so i have no idea how to format it based on multiple sets...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a CASE expression

```
update t1
   set check = case loc when '020201' then '10000'
                        when '020301' then '10100'
                        ... etc.
                        end
 where loc in ('020201','020301',...);
```

But frankly I would just write several singleton update statements:

```
update t1 set check = '10000' where loc = '020201';
update t1 set check = '10100' where loc = '020301';
.etc.
```

Comment: Of course! I feel a bit embarrassed now. Thank you Tony!